# Java how to access the property of instance of another class in the instance of outer class?

Tags: java, class, instance

I may use incorrect terms, sorry in advance.
I need to access a property from instance of another class that is located in the the instance of outer class. There will be two instances of class Outer and I need to store and process property "desiredProperty" for each of them individually.
Note: All classes are different. Inner1 and Inner2 are not the same classes!
Here is a simple example.

File 1:

```
public class Outer{

public Inner1 inner1 = new Inner1();
public Inner2 inner2 = new Inner2();

}
```

File 2:

```
public class Inner1 {

int desiredProperty=1;

}
```

File 3:

```
public class Inner2{

public int getDesiredProperty(){

//How can I here access the property DesiredProperty from Inner1?

}

}
```

Comment: You need to have a reference to an instance of Inner1. Are the classes related in any way (or just called Outer and Inner)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Inner2 class need to have an instance property for Inner1

```
public class Inner2{

private Inner1 inner1;

public Inner2(Inner1 inner1){
   this.inner1 = inner1;
}

public int getDesiredProperty(){
    return inner1.getDesiredProperty();    
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

first make a setter getter function in the Inner1 class, so you can get/set the value on Inner1

```
public class Inner1 {

int desiredProperty=1;
public int getDesiredProperty()
{
    return this.desiredProperty;
}

public void setDesiredProperty(int val)
{
    this.desiredProperty = val;
}

}
```

and in Inner2 class

```
public class Inner2{

public int getDesiredProperty(){

//How can I here access the property DesiredProperty from Inner1?
Inner1 inner1 = new Inner1();
return inner1.getDesiredProperty(); //value from Inner1
}

}
```